# php mysql + sessions errors

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

I'm creating a website that contains a login page, profile page and logout page. I'm using sessions but I have  a problem with dealing with sessions and I cannot understand what the error is or where it is to fix it.

The error I get is in the profile.php `**(("you need to be loged in to view profiles"))line 8**`
anyone have an idea or a solution plz tel me

## login.php

```
<?php 

 require_once('for members/scripts/global.php'); 

$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['email'])){

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];


  //error handeling
  if((!$email)||(!$pass)){
  $message = "please insert both fields";

  }else{
   // secure data
   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
   $pass = sha1($pass);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'AND password='$pass'LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
   $count_query = mysql_num_rows($query);
   if($count_query == 0){
   $message = "the information was incorrect!";
   }else{
   //start the sessions
   $_SESSION['pass']=$pass;
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       $username = $row['username'];
       $id = $row['id'];

    }
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

    /* to create a cookie on the HDD OF THE user 
    if($remember == "yes"){
    //create the cookies
    setcookie("id_cookie", $id, time()+60*60*24*100,"/");
    setcookie("pass_cookie", $pass, time()+60*60*24*100,"/");
    }
    */

     header("Location:profile.php");
   }
  }

}





?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>



<div class="container center"> 

<p><?php print("$message") ?></p>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress" /><br />

<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" /><br />

<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />

 <a href="register.php"><strong> Register</strong></a>

</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

## profile.php

```
<?php  
ob_start();
session_start();

require_once('for members/scripts/global.php'); 

if($logged == 0){
 echo("you need to be loged in to view profiles");
 exit();
}
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 $id= preg_replace("#[^0-9]#","",$id);

}else{
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
}
//collect member information
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$id'LIMIT 1") or die("could not collect user information ");
$count_mem = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count_mem == 0){
 echo("the user does not exit");
 exit();

}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  $username = $row['username'];
  $fname = $row['firstname'];
  $lname = $row['lastname'];
  $profile_id= $row['id'];

  if($session_id == $profile_id){
  $owner = true;
  }else{
   $owner = false;

  }

}



?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php print("$fname"); ?> <?php print("$lname"); ?>'s profile</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container center"> 
<h1><?php print("$username"); ?></h1>
<?php
if($owner == true ){
    header("Location: profile.php");
?>
<!--
<a href="#">edit profile</a><br />
<a href="#">account settings</a><br />
-->
<?php
}else{
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
<!--
<a href="#">private message</a><br />
<a href="#">add as friend</a><br />
--> 
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php flush(); ?>
```

## logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();

session_destroy();
/*
if(isset($_COOKIE['id_cookie'])){

setcookie("id_cookie", "", time()-50000,"/");

setcookie("pass_cookie", "", time()-50000,"/");

}
*/
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ 
echo("we could not log out try again!");
exit();
}else{
 header("Location: home.php");

}

?>
```

## global.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
session_start();
} 

require_once('connect.php'); 


//checking if sessions are set

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
 $session_username = $_SESSION['username'];
 $session_pass = $_SESSION['pass'];
 $session_id = $_SESSION['id'];

 //check if the member exist
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$session_id' AND password='$session_pass'LIMIT 1")or die("could not ");
$count_count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count_count == 0){
//loged in stuff here
$logged = 1;

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     $session_username = $row['username'];
  }
  //create sessions
$_SESSION['username'] = $session_username;
$_SESSION['id'] = $session_id;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $session_pass;


}else{
 header("Location: logout.php");
exit();
}



}
$logged = 0;
/*
elseif(isset($_COOKIE['id_cookie'])){
    $session_id = $_COOKIE['id_cookie'];
    $session_pass = $_COOKIE['pass_cookie'];

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$session_id' AND password='$session_pass'LIMIT 1")or die("could not ");
$count_count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count_count > 0){


//loged in stuff here
$logged = 1;
}else{
 header("Location: logout.php");
exit();
 }
 //if user is not log in

}
*/

?>
```

Comment: one thing you need to know is that you cannot send headers after you already start sending content. You have `header("Location:...")` after you already sent HTML/echo

Comment: in `profile.php`, what sets `$logged`?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$_SESSION` without properly starting the session with line `session_start()` in your login.php page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few thing that can be wrong with what you have written. The `$logged == 0` is defined in global.php I suppose. Is it starting the session in it as well (i.e., do you have `session_start()` in global.php)?

As far as I can see `$logged` could be whatever and thus you get the error. Starting the session in logging.php also should be fixed if not in global.php.

ok. Take everything out of global.php. If you want leave only session_start() but remove it from login.php and profile.php.

Then you have to move the sql query that checks the password and the username against the database to login.php instead of global.php and have it like this.

```
 //check if the member exist
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$session_id' AND   password='$session_pass'LIMIT 1")or die("could not ");
$count_count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count_count == 0){
//loged in stuff here
$logged = 1;
header("Location: profile.php");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     $session_username = $row['username'];
  }
  //create sessions
$_SESSION['username'] = $session_username;
$_SESSION['id'] = $session_id;
$_SESSION['pass'] = $session_pass;


}else{
 $logged = 0;
 header("Location: logout.php");
exit();
}
```

you do not need these in login.php (replace them with the code above)

```
$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['email'])){

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pass = $_POST['pass'];


  //error handeling
  if((!$email)||(!$pass)){
  $message = "please insert both fields";

  }else{
   // secure data
   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
   $pass = sha1($pass);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email'AND password='$pass'LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
   $count_query = mysql_num_rows($query);
   if($count_query == 0){
   $message = "the information was incorrect!";
   }else{
   //start the sessions
   $_SESSION['pass']=$pass;
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       $username = $row['username'];
       $id = $row['id'];

    }
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

Comment: yes the global .php contain a session_start()  but the second part of your answer i did not understand very well

Comment: If you don't have session_start() in global then you are using $_SESSION wrongly in login.php. You have to start the session. Now if you start the session in global why do you start it again in profile.php and what about the assignment of $logged. Please add the global.php in you question.

Comment: @ idipous  i edit my question and add global.php plz i need this help so badly

Comment: see my edit. You have several things misunderstood. If you copy and paste what I have written chances are it's not going to work right away but you will get really closer. It seems that you copy pasted code from different places or you have not understood some php concepts. Don't worry though you will make it.